# Repo sync from local mirror without internet connection

Tags: git, gitlab, repo

I created a local mirror in which I have bare repositories .git by specifying the URL of the gitlab project, branch and the --mirror option after a repo init and repo sync, after that I used the mirror to initialize a new repository locally with the --reference option. In fact I want the sources to be available on my local computer so I can use them when there's no internet connection, howerver when I use the mirror and disconnect the internet, repo sync on the second repository tries to get access to the internet to fetch and checkout all the branches of each project. My question is : Is there any way to fetch all of that on my local computer and just run a repo init then sync to have the sources?

Comment: `git clone path/to/your/local/mirror.git`? I'm not sure what you mean by "sync"

Comment: Sync on the second repository creates 2 directories on the .repo directory : Projects and project-objects. The project-objects has also .git repos (like the mirror I created but is heavier because it fetched refs of the projects) and the second projects directory has the source code of the projects. If I have these 2 directories on the .repo, I can run repo sync -l and it syncs correctly even without internet connection. The idea is to be able to create these two directories from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

In the `repo init` command, we use `-u` to specify which manifest repository to clone, `-b` to specify which branch to checkout, and `-m` to specify which manifest file on the branch to parse.

In the manifest file specified by `-m`, the element `default` has an attribute `fetch`. It refers to the url or the path where the remote repositories are hosted. And in each `project` element, the `name` attribute indicates the name of the remote repository.

In your case, you need 2 steps to customize the init & sync procedure.

1. Copy and edit the manifest file you want to use.
2. Commit the edited manifest file in a manifest repository.

Suppose your local mirror path is `/home/me/mirror/` and your local manifest repository is `/home/me/manifest`.

Copy the manifest, supposing its name is `foo.xml`, from the repository specified by `-u` to `/home/me/manifest`.

Open it and modify the `fetch` attribute in the `default` element. Here we use `file://` protocol repository url. Note that there are 3 `/` after `:`. The `...` in the following example means other possible attributes and values. Do not write the `...` in your manifest.

```
<default fetch="file:///home/me/mirror" name="origin" .../>
```

Add and commit the manifest in `/home/me/manifest`.

Download the code from the mirror repositories with the modified manifest.

```
repo init -u file:///home/me/manifest -b master -m foo.xml
repo sync
```

This way, `repo init` first clones the local repository `file:///home/me/manifest` to `.repo/manifest.git` and then checks out `master` to `.repo/manifests`. `repo sync` parses the manifest `.repo/manifests/foo.xml` and downloads each project from `file:///home/me/mirror`.

You could also commit and push the modified `foo.xml` to the repository you used before. But I think it may confuse others, so I suggest you keep it in a local manifest repository. Besides, when there is no internet connection, a local manifest repository can still work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was able to sync using the mirror. I just want to ask another question which is how do we apply an overlay on a default.xml manifest in order to add another remote which will point to a local mirror for example. The thing is that I managed to create this overlay using an xml file and include it to the default.xml manifest. The problem is that it is working only if I comment the old remote. Is there any way to keep the older fetch and add another remote to fetch the same metas and place them else where?

Comment: @Momo You can add multiple `remote` in a manifest as long as they have different `name`. The existing unique one is named `origin`. But if you want to use another remote instead of the one in `default`, you need to add the remote to the projects, like `<project name="foo" path="foo" remote="new_remote" />`. The manifest allows multiple projects with the same name, but it does not allow projects to have the same path. So, you'd better just create a different manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming that your bare AOSP mirror is in /mnt/aosp

```
repo init -u file:///mnt/aosp/platform/manifest.git -b android-12.0.0_r15
```